# UILabel with a background thats wrap the lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uilabel

I need to draw text with a background. I need the background to be not just a square but to wrap the lines.

So using the background color of a `UILabel` is no good for me.
I suppose I need to draw it, but I dont know how..
Just to be clear, I don't want a square background like this:

[image]

I want background like this:

[image]

p.s.
I really don't want to use more then one label to get this effect...
I also need it to support ios 4.3 so I can't use new things like `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: maybe you can use a font with background color

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it easily with UILabel element on iOS 4. For example you can override UILabel class and play with calculating text width and then setting black views to the background, which is not an easy job.

I suggest you to use UIWebView instead. You can simply use HTML and CSS rules.